# html tag not defined in XML or no any JAR file error message

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, taglib, xml-configuration

Apache Struts tag `html` cannot be resolved in either XML or the JAR files deployed with the application even if I have place Struts `html` jar in lib (using Struts 1.3 and Tomcat 7).

Answer (score 0):

Put `struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar` to the `web-inf/lib`. This file contains all necessary tag libraries. also make sure you have taglib directive in the JSP.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
```